# Tracking all changes made to a document on SharePoint 2010 within a web-part

Tags: 2010, auditing

I am building a site in SharePoint 2010 and I would like to have a webpart that will track and log who and when updates are being made to a specific document. The webpart will be featured on the homepage of the site so my team can track who has udpated the document. I am unable to find the right webpart or settings to do this. The content query which I have seen recommended multiple times does not appear to be an option for a web part for me. Any recommendations as to how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

I solved for this exact problem with a custom workflow which posts to a custom list.

The List:

- Columns for Created By (person/group), Activity (Text), Hyperlink (URL), Created (date/time)

The Workflow:

- Triggers whenever someone updates a document in the specified library (if you needed, you could use conditional blocks to isolate desired files)
- Runs a Create List Item action to post back to my custom list. It sets activity to say "I updated a file: [%Current Item:Name%]" and the hyperlink to Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL.
- Depending on how your environment handles content publishing/approval, you may also need to add a binary flag to the document itself which prevents it from double-posting on initial upload (the check in/approval is sometimes treated as a second update). Test without this, but if you're getting a double post create a "new file" yes/no field on the library which defaults to 0, and set a condition in the workflow that if the value is 0, instead of posting update it to 1.

The Output: You have a list / web part which displays the user who updated the file (most of my teams prefer it with pictures), the name of the file, and the date (or date/time) of the update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this. I am not very tech savvy however I do understand what you are saying. Do you know what steps I would need to take to get to the "lists" setup and or what web-part to select to be able to input the information?

Comment: Erica: To set up the list, you just need to add a new Custom List to your site and then configure it via the list settings to have those columns. Creating the workflow requires the SharePoint Designer application. The basics of these are heavily documented, here are some top results: [Download Designer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573), [Intro to workflows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635157/An-Introduction-to-SharePoint-Workflows), [Create a custom list](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/plan-and-create-custom-lists-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

Comment: If you're looking for an out of the box web part, there isn't one that will track this on its own. This is the simplest and easiest solution I've come across which produces a log of updates.